# Variable structure for database results

Tags: sql, delphi

A lot of times when we query the database, we just need one column with varchar.
So I've made a nice function for querying the database and putting the results in a stringlist:

```
function Getdatatostringlist(sqlcomponent, sqlquery: string): TStringlist;
```

What I'm looking for now is basically the same function but for results with multiple columns where you don't know in advance what type the data is, be it varchar, int, datetime.

What kind of datastructure would be good to use here.

The reason I want this is that I try not to work on open datasets. I like much more to fetch all results into a temporary structure, close the dataset and work on the results.

---

After Kobiks reply about using in Memory datasets I came up with the following, it's fast put together to test the concept:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyDataSet : TAdoDataSet;
begin
 MyDataSet := GetDataToDataSet('SELECT naam FROM user WHERE userid = 1', ADOConnection1);
 try
   Form1.Caption := MyDataSet.FieldByName('naam').AsString;
 finally
   MyDataSet.free;
 end;
end;

function TForm1.GetDataToDataSet(sSql: string; AdoConnection: TADOConnection): TAdoDataSet;
begin
  Result := TAdoDataSet.Create(nil);
  Result.LockType := ltBatchOptimistic;
  Result.Connection := AdoConnection;
  Result.CommandText :=  sSql;
  Result.Open;
  Result.Connection := nil;
end;
```

I think this is something to build on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use any disconnected in-memory `TDataSet` descendant, such as [`TClientDataSet`](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/a/tclientdataset.htm).

Do not attempt to re-invent the wheel by storing a record-set in some new "Variant" structure. A `TClientDataSet` already contains all features you need to manipulate a "temporary" data structure.

Here is how you create a `TClientDataSet` structure:

```
cds.FieldDefs.Add('id', ftInteger);
cds.FieldDefs.Add('name', ftString, 100);
// ...
// create it
cds.CreateDataSet; 
// add some data records
cds.AppendRecord([1, 'Foo']);
cds.AppendRecord([2, 'Bar']);
```

Many TDataSets has an ability to be used as an in-memory (client) datasets depending on the provider and `LockType`, for example a `TADODataSet` with `LockType=ltBatchOptimistic` could fetch results-set from the server, and then remain disconnected.

Comment: I think this is what I need to be looking into.

Answer (score 3):

For exchanging Data with Excel this structure is usefull, might be useful for other purposes.

```
Function GetDatasetasDynArray(Ads: TDataset; WithHeader: Boolean = true): Variant;
// 20130118 by Thomas Wassermann
var
  i, x, y: Integer;
  Fields: Array of Integer;
begin
  x := 0;
  y := Ads.RecordCount;
  if WithHeader then
    inc(y);
  SetLength(Fields, Ads.FieldCount);
  for i := 0 to Ads.FieldCount - 1 do
    if Ads.Fields[i].Visible then
    begin
      Fields[x] := i;
      inc(x);
    end;
  SetLength(Fields, x);
  Result := VarArrayCreate([0, y - 1 , 0, length(Fields) - 1], VarVariant);
  y := 0;
  if WithHeader then
  begin
    for i := Low(Fields) to High(Fields) do
    begin
      Result[y, i] := Ads.Fields[Fields[i]].DisplayLabel;
    end;
    inc(y);
  end;
  try
    Ads.DisableControls;
    Ads.First;
    while not Ads.EOF do
    begin
      for i := Low(Fields) to High(Fields) do
      begin
        Result[y, i] := Ads.Fields[Fields[i]].Value;
      end;
      Ads.Next;
      inc(y);
    end;
  finally
    Ads.EnableControls;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 DynArray:Variant;
begin

   DynArray := GetDatasetasDynArray(Adodataset1,true);
   //DynArray[0,x] Header or First row
   //DynArray[1,x] First row or SecondRow
   Excel.Range.Value := DynArray;
end;
```

Comment: Those variant arrays are so heavyweight to work with. I'd rather use simply `array of Variant` if I could, but if it's good for Excel data exchange... Although I think the best might be the `TCustomDataSet` suggested by @kobik. [+1]

Comment: @bummi we use some oleautomation and I think this approach is really suited for it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you like working with open datasets? They usually do not block the server.  Copying the data from the dataset to whatever you want is extra overhead which is most likely not necessary.

A dataset provides exactly the functionality you want: A matrix with variable columns and rows.

EDIT: However, if you have iterate through the dataset often, you should consider creating a class holding the relevant information and then copy the data into a generic list, dictionary, tree or whatever you need as fast lookup structure.

Of course you could think of building something smart which can be as flexible as a dataset but: The more general things get, the poorer the performance (usually).

Comment: We've ran into a few problems, 2 mostly:  1: performance really suffers with nested queries and because it's not always clear that a function which you use uses the database, so nesting is not always clear.   2: when working on open datasets it's hard to predict if the data is the same when you opened it as to like when you're halfway through it.

Comment: Once you open the dataset, it is static. There is no difference in copying the stuff to another structure or iterating through it. However, if performance is an issue, i.e. you would have to search things often, you -of course- have to copy the data into another structure: I would recommend a POCO class and a dictionary or similar.